# How to use sbt-revolver-like features for tests?

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

Is it possible to use `sbt-revolver` for testing or have something similar out of the (sbt) box?

I want to achieve such goals:

- no memory leaks, no uncleaned resources. (`~ test` doesn't give that)
- no `OutOfMemory` (`PermGen` space).
- don't hang up if a test hang up.
- ideally, don't wait for the old test to complete if I already changed the sources. Run a new test instead.

`sbt-revolver` has most of these things for "running" an app. But how can I use `sbt-revolver` to test?

Comment: sbt-revolver only handles the first two because it forks.  You can fork tests without it.

Comment: Are you proposing to fork the JVM manually?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by manually, but `fork in Test := true` will do it.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the key. The third and fourth goals are still desired anyway. So, let's see if anybody knows how to achieve them, too.

Comment: re: #3, if you're a ScalaTest user you might go express interest in https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/97

Comment: @SethTisue thanks, seems interesting! As I thought about it now, maybe the desired thing can be achieved even more simpler: SBT has to kill the forked JVM if the sources change. Maybe I should fill in such issue, or even try implement the idea?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Maybe run it by https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sbt-dev